# Reversing the order of a list of lists or list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-2.x

I have a list of tuples:

`ls = [('hello', 'there'), ('whats', 'up'), ('no', 'idea')]`

I want to reverse the order of each tuple in the list.

`ls = [('there', 'hello'), ('up', 'whats'), ('idea', 'no')]`

I know tuples are immutable so I'll need to create new tuples. I'm not really sure what's the best way to go about it. I could change the list of tuples into a list of lists, but I'm thinking there might be a more efficient way to go about this.

Comment: in python2, `map(reversed, ls)` would have sufficed, in python3 you'd have to write `list(map(tuple, map(reversed, ls)))` for the same result. list comprehension is a better way to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) along the following lines:

```
ls = [tpl[::-1] for tpl in ls]
```

This uses the typical `[::-1]` [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) pattern to reverse the tuples.

Also note that the list itself is not immutable, so if you needed to mutate the original list, and not just rebind the `ls` variable, you could use [slice assignment](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/3048/slice-assignment):

```
ls[:] = [tpl[::-1] for tpl in ls]
```

This is the short-hand equivalent of a loop-based approach à la:

```
for i, tpl in enumerate(ls):
    ls[i] = tpl[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Input:

`ls = [('hello', 'there'), ('whats', 'up'), ('no', 'idea')]`

```
ls = [(f,s) for s,f in ls]
print(ls)
```

Output:

`[('there', 'hello'), ('up', 'whats'), ('idea', 'no')]`